# Reading from and manipulating a .csv file

Tags: vb.net

I have multiple .csv files for each month which go like:

```
01/04/2012,00:00,7.521527,80.90972,4.541667,5.774305,7,281.368
02/04/2012,00:00,8.809029,84.59028,6.451389,5.797918,7,274.0764
03/04/2012,00:00,4.882638,77.86806,1.152778,15.13611,33,127.6389
04/04/2012,00:00,5.600694,50.35417,-3.826389,15.27222,33,40.05556
```

The format is : Date in the form dd/mm/yy,Current time,Current temperature,Current humidity,Current dewpoint,Current wind speed,Current wind gust,Current wind bearing

The program needs to calculate the average for 
temperature
humidity
wind speed
wind direction

and display them on a text box.

any ideas?

Here is what I have done so far...

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.IO
Imports System

Public Class Form1   

Private Sub cmb1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmb1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnexit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btndata.Click
    'This is for August
    If cmb1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        TextBox1.Clear()
        Using reader As New StreamReader("c://temp/DailyAug12log.csv")
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            Dim avgTemp As Integer
            Dim fields() As String = line.Split(",".ToCharArray())
            Dim fileDate = CDate(fields(0))
            Dim fileTime = fields(1)
            Dim fileTemp = fields(2)
            Dim fileHum = fields(3)
            Dim fileWindSpeed = fields(4)
            Dim fileWindGust = fields(5)
            Dim fileWindBearing = fields(6)

            While line IsNot Nothing
                counter = counter + 1
                line = reader.ReadLine()
            End While
            avgTemp = CInt(fields(2))
            avgTemp = CInt(CDbl(avgTemp / counter))
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "Month = August" & vbCrLf & "Temperature Average: " & avgTemp & vbCrLf
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim files() As String
    files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Temp", "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each FileName As String In files
        cmb1.Items.Add(FileName.Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1, FileName.Length - FileName.LastIndexOf("\") - 1))
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need another variable to track how many lines you've read.  Just increment it by one for each line.  Then divide your "total" variable by the number of lines and update your textbox with the computed value.  You could declare other "total" variables to total up the other measurements as well...

Comment: thanks im working on it! any ideas on how to add this in? thanks!

Comment: Seriously?...declare the counter for the lines in the same place/fashion as the "total" variable.  It would be of type Integer.  Increment that variable by one in the same place that you accumulate the total variable at.  Do you think you should compute the average inside or outside the while loop?  What data type should be used for the average?  Integer or Double?

Comment: Hi i have tried this but my counter is not working. It is calculating my avg as 0. I have the counter inside the while loop and the average calculating outside the loop. can you give me an example of what you think i should be doing?

Comment: i have updated the above code with what i have now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Class Weather
    Public SampleTimeStamp AS Date
    Public Temperature AS Double
    Public Humidity As Double
    Public WindSpeed AS Double
    Public WindBearing AS Double
End Class

Sub Main
    Dim samples = ReadFile("c://temp/DailyAug12log.csv")

    Dim avgTemperature = samples.Average(Function(s) s.Temperature)
    ...
End Sub

Private Function ReadFile(ByVal fileName as String) AS List(Of Weather)
    Dim samples As New List(Of Weather)
    Using tfp As new TextFieldParser(filename)
        tfp.Delimiters = new String() { "," }
        tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited

        While Not tfp.EndOfData
            Dim fields = tfp.ReadFields()
            Dim sample As New Weather()

            sample.SampleTimeStamp = Date.ParseExact(fields(0) & fields(1), "dd\/MM\/yyyyHH\:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            sample.Temperature = Double.Parse(fields(2), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            sample.Humidity = Double.Parse(fields(3), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            sample.WindSpeed = Double.Parse(fields(4), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            sample.WindBearing = Double.Parse(fields(5), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            samples.Add(sample)
        End While

        Return samples
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I display the averages for each into a textbox? :)

Comment: TextBox.Text = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Average temperature is {0}", avgTemperature)

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a this aprroach - if the order of the columns changes, your program will show wrong results.
I would use a good csv reader like http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/ and read the Data to a datatable. then you can calculate your resulting columns quite easily and reliablly, because you can adress each column like MyDatatable.Cooumns["Headername"].